# In Corda, deployNodes fails with "Could not determine java version from 'X.Y.Z'."

Tags: corda

I have downloaded the Example CorDapp (https://github.com/corda/cordapp-example), and am trying to run the `deployNodes` task from the command line.

When I do so, I receive the following error:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> * What went wrong:
>
> Could not determine java version from 'X.Y.Z'.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of version 3, Corda currently only runs against JDK 8 (versions 8u131 and above). You have another JDK version installed. You need to switch to JDK 8 and re-run the `deployNodes` task.

On macOS, you can do this by running the command:

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8`
```